# Having datetime only go up to minutes in my time column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am pulling information from our server and the time column goes all the way to nanoseconds. I need to merge multiple dfs and this specificity is causing my script to return an empty df.

I tried using:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format="%d-%m-%y %H:%M")
```

but I do not believe that what I am trying to do is done through the "format" parameter.

I was going to convert the time column to strings and then parse to the correct number of characters but I really want to avoid converting to strings and then back to datetime.

Can what I am looking to do be done using to_datetime() or must I convert to strings, parse and convert back to datetime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the round() method on Timestamps to convert the column to the resolution you wish.

For example

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.now()).round('H')
```

Returns

```
Timestamp('2019-12-11 22:00:00')
```

as it converts the current time (to nanosecond frequency) to the nearest hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df = df.assign(Time=df.loc[:, 'Time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%m-%y %H:%M")))
```

Replace your first dataframe with one that has df['Time'] with datetime values, based on the current values and format of the Time column